# Selenium webdriver : I want to click on "Like 1.3M" image which is on the bottom of https://www.msn.com/en-in/weather/today

Tags: image, selenium, xpath, iframe, webdriver

I want to click on "Like 1.3M" image which is on the bottom of https://www.msn.com/en-in/weather/today

i have tried multiple approches for clicking on "facebook like" image like switching to iframe , clicking on image in webdriver.

but none of them are working .

Comment: Show your example code that you have tried and errors that you're getting. That way, someone can help with the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have no specified any language I will use Python to answer your question.
Firstly you need to switch to `iframe` that contains the like button like:

```
driver.get("https://www.msn.com/en-in/weather/today")
iframe = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="fbcount"]/iframe')))
iframe.location_once_scrolled_into_view
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
```

and then click like:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="u_0_0"]/div/button').click()
```

and then switch to default content

```
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

If you get `NoSuchElementException` please add some wait time.

Here is the full code

```
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

driver = webdriver.Chrome("/chromedriver/location")

driver.get("https://www.msn.com/en-in/weather/today")
iframe = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="fbcount"]/iframe')))
iframe.location_once_scrolled_into_view
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
time.sleep(3)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="u_0_0"]/div/button').click()
time.sleep(3)
driver.switch_to.default_content()

driver.close()
driver.quit()
```

Comment: Ty @tek-nath ,below is java code from above code reference , 
but click is not working .

~
driver.get("https://www.msn.com/en-in/weather/today");
WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(driver, 20); 
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver; js.executeScript("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)"); Thread.sleep(20000); 

WebElement iframe= wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath( "//*[@id=\"fbcount\"]/iframe")));
driver.switchTo().frame(iframe); 
Thread.sleep(5000); driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='u_0_0']/div/button")).click();
~

Comment: -No error , code is moving to next line successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of click(), use the action class click().

```
WebElement likeFB=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='u_0_0']/div/button"));
Actions act = new Actions(driver);
act.moveToElement(likeFB).click().build().perform();
```